# OpenCV 2.4.1 static linking with Qt

Tags: c++, opencv, static-libraries, static-linking, undefined-reference

I have compile OpenCV 2.4.1 statically without error using MinGW and CMake. I checked `With_QT`

I just unchecked `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` and proceed with  `mingw32-make` and `mingw32-make install`.

It was built without error and eventually I have bunch of `.a` file in the lib folder of opencv.

But after setting `LIBS and INCLUDEPATH` parameters of .pro file and running a simple application in Qt I have got errors.

I also add the following line to `.pro` file:

```
CONFIG += -static -static-libgcc
```

I provided last line error:

```
F:\OpenCV2.4.1\opencv-static\install\lib\libopencv_highgui241.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.obj):grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x4f):
undefined reference to `jas_image_decode'  collect2: ld returned 1
exit status  mingw32-make[1]: ***

[release\test.exe] Error 1 
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2  The process "C:/ming44/bin/mingw32-make.exe" exited with code %2. Error while building project test (target: Desktop) When executing build step 'Make'
```

**Update**

I figured out that the error is just when I call `highgui.hpp` methods. like the following error when I use `cv::imshow()`:

```
F:\OpenCV2.4.1\opencv-static2\install\lib\libopencv_highgui241.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL17icvCreateTrackbarPKcS0_PiiPFviEPFviPvES4_+0x5e1): undefined reference to `CreateToolbarEx@52'  collect2: ld returned 1
exit status  mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\test.exe] Error 1 
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: It is evident that you forgot to link against [libjasper](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/libjasper) a 3rd party dependency of OpenCV. Did you even build it? If you did, then just link against it too. I think the error message makes it obvious, for instance, I've never worked with OpenCV, but looking through their repository I immediately understood what's your problem and how to fix it. So the side question is: are you sure you understand how linking works?

Comment: @Haroogan I checked the option BUILD_JASPER while building opencv. But there is no lib file created. I thought the procedure is similar to building in shared mode.

Comment: Look at [CreateToolbarEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787469(v=vs.85).aspx), scroll-down and see that this symbol is defined in either `Comctl32.lib` or `Comctl32.dll`. Now, guess what? Maybe it's time to link against one of these ones too (so that the symbol is resolved)? The side question is still open, as you cannot resolve the simple problem yourself over and over again.

Comment: @Haroogan Thanks. I know how static linking works. my problem is that how can I find which library .a file should be linked to solve errors. I understood that I need to link against Comct32.a, right? but where can I find it?

Comment: This is a system library, and therefore it is supplied with the toolchain, MinGW in your case. For instance, in my MinGW-w64 distribution the `libcomctl32.a` is located at `D:\Toolchains\x64\MinGW-w64\4.7.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib`. Such library paths are searched by default when MinGW compiles and links your application. That's why, to link properly to `libcomctl32.a`, all you have to add is: `-lcomctl32`.

Comment: @Haroogan And do you know where can I find `vfw32.a` cause I got another error that needs it.  `undefined reference to AVIStreamRelease@4'`

Comment: Ha-Ha, no really, are you kidding? `:)` In my MinGW-w64 distribution the `libvfw32.a` is in `D:\Toolchains\x64\MinGW-w64\4.7.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib`, i.e. in the same directory as `libcomctl32.a`. Was it so hard to check? I can imagine that you have some crappy outdated MinGW distribution where it is not present. If so, just let me know, and I'll tell you where to get bleeding-edge MinGW distributions.

Comment: :) yeah. stupid question. can you tell me how to find which .a file can remove specific error? I mean how can I find that `comct32.a` can solve previous problem? cause I got another error `undefined reference to cv::dft` and I don't know which lib is required.

Comment: There is no direct way to do it. Speaking in the first place, it should be the documentation that should clearly state in which module the symbol is defined. I don't see it in the OpenCV documentation, and that's crap, so I understand your problem. However, you should still be able to cope with problems like that regardless of how crappy the developers of the library are. I promise this is the last time I'm searching the symbol for you, so `cv::dft` is defined in the [Core component](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp). Link with `opencv_core` to resolve it.

Comment: It is always good to use file content searching utility such as `grep` (popular on Unix OS family). This way you could, for example, do `grep -r "void.*dft(" .` in the root of OpenCV source tree, and track down where that symbol is defined in no time. If you want to be productive software developer capable of solving such day-to-day routines rapidly, then `grep` is just one of many utilities which should undoubtedly be the part of your tooling arsenal. Would you like me to summarize all that stuff as an answer?

Comment: that was so helpful. I'd appreciate your summarize answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were many questions as we proceeded through the fix process, so I'll try to summarize the answers to all of them here.

### Unresolved Symbols

---

```
undefined reference to `jas_image_decode'
```

The `jas_image_decode` symbol is defined in [libjasper](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/libjasper) (which is a 3rd party dependency of OpenCV). To resolve it, link against `libjasper.a`.

```
undefined reference to `CreateToolbarEx@52'
```

The `CreateToolbarEx` symbol is part of Windows API, and is therefore defined in system libraries (which are always supplied with a toolchain, MinGW in your case). You can always find against which library you should link to resolve such symbols by looking in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (scroll down and see **Library** and **DLL** cells). In this case, you can see `Comctl32.lib`, however MSDN of course posts names of libraries in the format that Microsoft Visual C toolchain defines them. Since you are using MinGW toolchain, you'd have to convert (mentally) this name into the Unix naming convention of libraries, and in this case that would be `libcomctl32.a`.

```
undefined reference to `AVIStreamRelease@4'
```

Similarly to the previous case we find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and infer that we have to link against `libvfw32.a`.

**NOTE:** The paths to such system libraries (containing Windows API) are always searched automatically by the toolchain. Therefore, you shouldn't supply `-L` option during compilation/linkage, but only the library itself, i.e. `-lcomctl32`.

```
undefined reference to `cv::dft'
```

Well, that's again some component from OpenCV (`cv` namespace obviously suggests that). A bit of searching reveals that it is defined in the [Core component](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp). Accordingly, to resolve that symbol, link against `libopencv_core.a`.

### The Approach

---

> How do I find out which library to link against to resolve the missing symbol?

There is no rule of thumb or any direct recipe here, but rather a number of tricks and educated guesses which primarily come from experience. Here are a few examples:

1. For instance, in case of `CreateToolbarEx`, it was quite easy for me
   to guess that it belongs to Windows API as long as I recognize the
   Windows API naming convention of the function name. Consequently,
   what I do next is type `CreateToolbarEx` into Google, jump to the
   corresponding page on MSDN, scroll down, see what the library name
   is, convert (mentally) to the Unix naming convention of libraries (see above),
   and voila!
2. The case of OpenCV is more tricky. OpenCV is a 3rd party library and
   the question whether it'll be painful to find out the library where
   certain symbol is defined solely depends on the quality of the
   documentation provided. Although, I can see that the OpenCV
   documentation is pretty good, it is still missing these important
   hints for every symbol, and that's a pity. However, we (developers)
   have to be able to cope with problems like that regardless of how
   crappy the documentation of a 3rd party library is, and get the job done.

   That's why it is always a good idea to use file content searching utility
   such as `grep` (popular on Unix OS family, but available for Windows
   too in [MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/MSYS) distribution). This way, for example in case of
   `cv::dft`, you could run `grep -r "void.*dft(" .` in the root of
   OpenCV source tree, and track down where that symbol is defined in
   no time. After that you'd have to infer to which component the file
   containing `cv::dft` belongs, but that should be straightforward, just look
   around and see in which directory the file resides.

### Conclusion

---

I swear that I've never used OpenCV in my life, but as you can see I was still able to locate all these missing symbols for you. As a result, we can conclude that the proposed techniques of searching for unresolved symbols are sort of reliable.

Finally, nothing of this is specific to OpenCV or Qt. You're dealing with basic programmer craftsmanship skills here. If you want to be productive software developer capable of solving such day-to-day routines rapidly, then `grep` is just one of many essential utilities which should undoubtedly be the part of your tooling arsenal.